# Vue3 Plugin Typescript Typings

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, rollup

I'm trying to write a plugin with Vue3 in Typescript. However, I'm stuck from the start with how to properly type the plugin function.

This is what I have so far:

```js
import MyComponent from './src/components/my-component.vue'

import { DefineComponent, Plugin } from 'vue'

const plugin: Plugin = {
    install (app, options?: { [key: string]: any }) {
        app.mixin({
            computed: {
                classes (this: DefineComponent) {
                    // ...do things to `this`
                }
            }
        })

        app.component('MyComponent', MyComponent)
    }
}

export default plugin
```

One of the biggest problems is how to deal with `this` in the context of these functions. There's just red all over the screen at the moment.

I'm trying to use `rollup` for bundling.

This shows no errors, but when imported into another Vue project it blows up.

How to properly type a plugin function using Typescript, Vue3 and Rollup?

Comment: Using `this` as the first argument is a Typescript thing. It lets the compiler know what `this` actually is.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but the above code does actually work.

After deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling, everything worked.

I'm leaving this question up because it took a while to find `Plugin`.

```
import { DefineComponent, Plugin } from 'vue'

const plugin: Plugin = {
    install (app, options?) {
       app.mixin({
           computed: {
               classes (this: DefineComponent) {
                   // Do stuff here. Even with `this`
               }
           }
       })
    } 
}
```

Using `this` as the first argument of a function tells the Typescript compiler what `this` actually is.